# Mixed model structure on TOP

Tags: homotopy-theory

Is the mixed model structure on TOP (Weak homotopy equivalences + Hurewicz fibrations) cofibrantly generated?

Comment: See the argument of "Homotopy of posets" by G. Raptis, Homology Homotopy Appl. 12 (2010), no. 2, 211–230, Remark 4.7. It would suffice to prove that for any cardinal $\mu$, there exists a cardinal $\nu > \mu$ such that the topological space $\mathcal{T}(P_\nu)$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex.

Comment: Great, thank you!